# how to transition just for transform rotate

Tags: css

I have an HTML element that must rotate in a hover event. look at the code. I don't want transition for translateX. I just want transition for rotate. what should I do??

```
.cog {
    margin-top: 250px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.cog:hover {
    transform: rotate(-.4turn);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the translation on hover too:

```css
.cog {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
}

.cog:hover {
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-.4turn);
}
```

```html
<div class="cog"></div>
```

Comment: nice It works, but could you explain what happens exactly when I add translate to my hover too??

Comment: @MohammadHadyKarimi I would probably explain what happens if you *don't* add it. you are using translate to center your element so if you remove it on hover your element will no more be centred. So you keep the translate and you add the rotate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Remove the transform property from `cog` class. Then it will only rotate.

**CSS**

```
.cog {
    margin-top: 250px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}

.cog:hover {
    transform: rotate(-.4turn);
}
```